# Unwanted GRUB on internal drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, bootloader

Past week I bought a new laptop (Asus K541U series) and an external HDD (Seagate 1TB extension portable). The laptop came with a preinstalled version of Windows 10 and I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on the external HDD. This worked out pretty well as long as I keep the external HDD connected. In this case I get the GRUB menu in which I can choose between Windows or Ubuntu. On the other hand, when the Ubuntu drive is unplugged, the pc boots into some GRUB command line ("grub> ") . I can exit this screen by entering "exit" after which Windows starts normally. So no severe problems, but it would all be smoother if Windows would just start with the external drive unplugged.

I tried fixing the Windows bootloader by using a recovery drive and running bootrec.exe in the command window but this didn't fix the problem.
While installing Ubuntu, I also made sure to install the Ubuntu bootloader on the external HDD. Apparently there is still some part of GRUB installed on the internal drive.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Kind regards!

Comment: Any factory installed Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode.  All you need is to change the boot priority and give it (again) to Windows. Change it to Ubuntu when you want to boot Ubuntu (and have the external drive connected, of course). DO NOT apply any "old fix" for BIOS/MBR or you will end up booting none!

Comment: @MichaelBay Thank you for your response. What you suggested did indeed make the startup smoother. Also now I can easily just choose to start Ubuntu from the boot menu pressing F8. Problem fixed! :)